# How to pronounce "Ephemerides"?

Tags: pronunciation, greek

I've always pronounced "Ephemerides" (plural of Ephemeris) using four syllables, the fourth being "Ides" as in the "Ides of March".

But in [this talk](https://youtu.be/FVEEndIwOSA?t=585)<sup>1</sup> at a few seconds after 10:10, it is pronounced with five syllables, the last two sounding like "[Pleiades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades)."

Are both acceptable, are there rules or guidelines for choosing a preferred pronunciation between the two?

---

<sup>1</sup>just in case the link breaks: "Skyfield and 15 Years of Bad APIs - Brandon Rhodes" PyCon Canada, August 16, 2013

Comment: _Pleiades_ has two common pronunciations, neither of whose final syllables sound like those in _ephimerides_ to me. Could you include a phonetic transcription to make it quite clear what exactly the pronunciations you're asking about are? FWIW, I've only ever heard _ephimerides_ (like all other Greek _-is/-ides_ words) pronounced as [Wiktionary gives it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ephemerides), with final /ɪdiːz/ and antepaenultimate stress.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I assume uhoh has the weak vowel merger and is saying both sound like they end in /ədiːz/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am not familliar enough with pronunciation notation to write it myself. It is given in the first line of the link for [Pleiades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades) which I have just re-linked to the correct taget (sorry about that!) The pronunciation in the video sounds to me like the pronunciation I have heard for Pleiades. This is the best I can do at the moment. I will meet a linguist today who will help me sort this out, thanks!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Well, for some "is-ides" words that had a long iota in Greek, there is the option of stressing that in the plural. For example, the OED mentions /æpˈsaɪdiːz/ ("ap-**SIDE**-eez") for *apsides.* But it says /ˈæpsɪdiːz/ is also "common", and that would be more consistent with the usual pronunciation of other similar words such as "matrices", "dominatrices" etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I actually knew someone who used *pre*-antepenultimate stress on that word, stressing PHEM but still with five rather rushed syllables.

Comment: @tchrist Well, they clearly didn't know their Ancient Greek stress allocation restrictions. For shame!

Comment: If you're asking whether that should be something like *rides* or *ride-ease* both my astrology teachers and used *ride-ease* and all their coupole of dozen students were already using *ride-ease* before signing up…

Comment: I have usually heard this pronounced with a one syllable short *i*, rhyming with “banana bids”. This was mainly from programmers who were actually working with the data in real life.

Comment: @GlobalCharm "'Ephemerids' and katydids and little lams eat ivy." Sounds good to me :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All sources I've found say *ephemerides* is pronounced /ɛfɪˈmɛrɪdiːz/ ("effih-**MERR**ih-deez", which for some speakers is the same as "effuh-**MERR**uh-deez").

Nobody uses the /aɪdz/ ("ide's") pronunciation, as far as I know. It would be justified if the singular were *ephemeride* ending in /aɪd/ ("ide"). However, "ephemeride" doesn't seem to exist as a singular noun.

The singular is instead *ephemeris,* from Ancient Greek *[ἐφημερῐ́ς](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CF%86%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%AF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) (ephēmeris).*

According to Wiktionary, the plural of *ἐφημερῐ́ς* was *ἐφημερῐ́δες (ephēmerides).* Basically, it's just become conventional to pronounce the letters "es" as /iːz/ ("eez") at the end of plural words of this type (ones that follow the Greek or Latin form rather than being formed with normal English pluralization rules).

"Ides" is a different type of loanword. It's not just a transliteration of a Greek form. The Latin word was *īdūs*, a plural of the fourth declension. This developed to French and English *ides* where the *e* just represents a schwa or the length of the preceding vowel, and the "s" is the usual plural suffix.

Comment: The octopodes post is very helpful, as are other answers there as well. I'll work with a linguist later today to help me with the pronunciation notation. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Yes! I now see that "Pleiades" is was a poor choice. While the induced flashback to second grade caught me off-guard, this is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Noting that 'ephemeral' is pronounced /e 'fem ə rə/ and 'hyperbole' /hai 'pɚ bə li:/ and 'sequipedalian' /se skwi pə 'dei li ən/, you said all that without remarking pedantically that Greek borrowings into English usually put stress on the _antepenultimate_. I mean where else can you use that word?

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to [@herisson's excellent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/370656/167396), the following three online dictionaries provide an *audio link* for the pronunciation of the plural noun. The audio is embedded in each web page so I can't insert the audio links here, but I've included a link to the page and an edited excerpt of the dictionary entry in each case:

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ephemerides)

> ephem·​er·​is | \ i-ˈfe-mə-rəs \
> *plural* **ephemerides** \ ˌe-​fə-​ˈmer-​ə-​ˌdēz \

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ephemeris)

> **ephemeris** (ɪˈfɛmərɪs)
> plural **ephemerides** (ˌɛfɪˈmɛr**ɪ**ˌdiːz)

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ephemeris)

> ephemeris [ ih-fem-er-is ] [IPA: / ɪˈfɛm ər ɪs /]
> plural **e·phe·mer·i·des**  /ˌɛf əˈmɛr ɪˌdiz/.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! The difference in *mɛr* between the first two is pronounced (pardon the intended pun)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to look at the dilemma.  Look at what the singular ending -is.  It is in Greek an adjectival form, indicating son or daughter of.  The genitive singular form becomes '-idis' and the nominative plural becomes '-ides'.

So Peisistratos who became 'tyrant' in Athens 546BCE till his death in 527.  The tyranny was maintained by his next two male generations till their overthrow in 510.  Collectively, they were known by the clan name of 'Peisistratides (Πεισιστρατιδες)', or the 'Peisistratid clan'.  One of them is called a *Peisistratis (Πεισιστρατις)*.  But the singular is not often found, because clans are generally and inevitably plural.  Historians of ancient Greek history, though, use *Peisistratid* rather than *peisistratis* as the true 'base' or 'stem' word. And they use the anglo-saxon '-s' to form the plural.

Clan names come a lot into Greek tragedy, also.  The daughters of King Danaus (the *Danaides - Δαναιδες*), in English *Danaids* are fleeing from forced marriage to the sons of Aegyptos and come to Argos to plead for (Hiketeuo) refuge to the king Pelasgos.  The tetralogy (three tragedies and a satyr play) is called *The Danaids - Δαναιδες* or *Daughters of Danaus*.  In English this translates to *The Danaids*, and the one surviving individual tragedy is called *Hiketides - Ικετιδες*. This usually comes into English as *Suppliants* or *Suppliant Women*.  Plays at this time were often named for their choruses, which, in this play, consisted of the suppliant daughters of Danaus.  Their natural number is plural, not singular: The are a plurality, just like members of a family.

Just as the chorus was a plurality, so, to the ancient watcher of the night sky, constellations were and are by definition pluralities, or, in other words, a sort of 'plural unit'.  On the analogy of *Peisistratid*, one member of the ephemerides would be an *ephemerid*, but more commonly thought of as *one of the ephemerides* and one of the Pleiades would be a *Pleiad* but more naturally as a *member of (or just one of) the Pleiades*.  The Cambridge English dictionary gives 'Pleiades' as the spelling.

Comment: Thank you for adding this wonderful and helpful answer!

Comment: @uhoh - But I left out the pronunciation.  There are two classes of ending in '-ides':  one for astronomical terms like ephemerides in English.  It is 'id-ez' (not '-eyedz').  But, as I hope I explained, it is quite common to omit the final 'e' and pronounce '-idz', which is the more fully anglicised version.  But there is a second class of chemical terms like 'peptide'.  The  'ide' part is derived from the Greek word 'eidos' ('ειδος'), meaning 'form' or 'type'.  Classicists till 60 years ago mispronounced the 'ei' as 'eye' and were copied by scientists.  So 'pepteyedz' it is (they are).